# Is there any penalty for skipping too many edits?

Tags: support, review-queues

Sometimes I am just lazy to evaluate the more lengthy edits, especially when they concern topics I am not familiar with. I guess this is probably okay but a confirmation would be great.

Comment: [Related](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip).

Comment: Honestly as soon as I get into a "hmmm... not entirely sure", and I don't feel like looking more in depth to figure out if it's appropriate or not, I prefer to skip than incorrectly review.

Comment: No. I skip ~95% of the edit reviews and didn't receive any negative feedback.

Comment: @Floern ah.. but this is not so good to the more diligent reviewers, who are getting more of the 'nasty' work

Comment: @prusswan but if you're freely giving some of your time... I actually appreciate it, whether you do 99% or 5% of the reviews you are presented. I prefer people to skip their review than review crappily. Since the intent of reviewing is to help Stack's quality. I think that making sure your review is GOOD is the important part

Comment: While there's nothing *wrong* with skipping lots of edits, the whole design of the edit system is that you should virtually never require domain knowledge to evaluate the edit, so if you're constantly skipping edits because they require domain knowledge, odds are most of those edits *should just be rejected*.  If you're really skipping a *lot* of edits it's not harming the system, per say, but it's wasting a lot of your own time skipping edits that you probably don't actually need to be skipping.

Comment: @prusswan I only review the edits that need to be rejected, independent of their complexity, and leave the approval of edits to the robo-reviewers.

Comment: @prusswan "not so good to the more diligent reviewers, who are getting more of the 'nasty' work " -> I like cooking and hate doing the dishes. My girlfriend hates cooking but doesn't mind doing the dishes. It's the same on SO. Some people don't mind reviews or even enjoy them, others hate doing it. There is no shame in not liking to do it, and you should under no circumstance feel "responsible" to do reviews. Do your own bits that you actually *enjoy* to contribute to the site!

Comment: **["learn to love that Skip button"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153279/165773)**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No.

Reviews are entirely voluntary and we (the community) are grateful that you're doing even a single one.

If anything, the skip button should be used *more often* by reviewers who can't be bothered to do a good job and do a half-arsed job instead. So good on you that you're skipping reviews!